# MongoDB service: Failed to open logfile permission denied

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to restart mongodb service after replacing mongod.conf file with bindip,replication name..etc.But unfirtunately it is failing and stating as unable to open logfile permission denied.But even if i gave 777 perm same issue

```
cat /etc/mongod.conf
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "/data/log/test.log"
  logAppend: true
net:
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
  port: 27017
storage:
  dbPath: "/data/dbdata/"

replication:
  replSetName: "rs0"
```

## Error message:

```
msg":"Error during global initialization","attr":{"error":{"code":38,"codeName":"FileNotOpen","errmsg":"Failed probe for \"/data/log/test.log\": Permission denied"}}}
```

## Permission on server:

```
ls -la /data/log
total 0
drwxrwxrw-. 2 mongod mongod 22 Jun  7 06:33 .
drwxrwxrw-. 5 mongod mongod 42 Jun  7 05:34 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 mongod mongod  0 Jun  7 06:33 test.log
ls -la /data/
total 0
drwxrwxrw-.  5 mongod mongod  42 Jun  7 05:34 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root   root   236 May  4 17:30 ..
drwxrwxrw-.  2 mongod mongod   6 Jun  7 05:34 dbdata
drwxrwxrw-.  2 mongod mongod  22 Jun  7 06:33 log
ls -ld /data
drwxrwxrw-. 5 mongod mongod 42 Jun  7 05:34 /data
```

NOTE: /data/dbdata,/data/log are mountpoints

Comment: That error message looks like it is treating the quotation marks as part of the file name.  Try removing the quotes from the file paths in the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by followed the steps present in the official documentation which required for selinux setup

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/#std-label-install-rhel-configure-selinux

```
yum install -y policycoreutils-python-utils

semanage fcontext -a -t mongod_var_lib_t /data/dbdata.*
semanage fcontext -a -t mongod_log_t /data/log.*


chcon -Rv -u system_u -t mongod_var_lib_t /data/dbdata
chcon -Rv -u system_u -t mongod_log_t /data/log


restorecon -R -v /data/dbdata
restorecon -R -v /data/log
```